# How to set numbers as commands in Telegram bot

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I want to set numeric commands for my bot in Telegram using BotFather.

When I enter a list such as:

```
1 - Menu
2- Change Source Language
3- Change Target Language
10 - Remove User Data
```

My expectation is to send /1 to bot to get the menu and /10 to receive Remove User Data,

But what I get instead is:

```
/0  --> Menu
/1  --> Change Source Language
/2 ---> Change Target Language
/3 --> Remove User Data
```

Is there anyway to tell BotFather not to ignore numbers?

Comment: Please ask [@BotSupport](https://t.me/BotSupport).

Comment: @Sean Thanks for advice. I asked them hope they will reply.

Comment: @BotSupport  haven't replied after 2 days.  Will they normally reply message?

Comment: Of course, you can ping them again

Answer (score 0):

It seems Botfather only accepts commands that

- don't have uppercase letters
- don't start with a number
- are max 32 characters long

See https://core.telegram.org/bots#6-botfather

Description max. 256 letters, min. 3 letters

https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.botcommand.html#telegram.BotCommand